# Javascript in applescript document.querySelectorAll('input[name$=_comment1]');

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I am trying to fill all the text fields in Safari where the name ends with _comment1 with a number obtained from a dialog query.

The source code of the text field looks like:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" name="233941_142117_comment1" value="" onKeyUp="return autoTab (this, 6, event);" onChange="disableButtons();">
```

It doesn't fill the fields though. Any ideas?

My applescript is:

```
set query to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Query" default answer "" buttons {"Input", "Cancel"} default button 1)
log "2"
activate application "Safari"
log "3"
tell application "Safari"


log "4"
do JavaScript "

    let x = document.querySelectorAll('input[name$=_comment1]');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].value = query;
     }

"
```

end tell

Comment: Never, under no circumstances, post code as image.

Comment: okay. code from browser looks like this:        <input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" name="233941_142117_comment1" value="" onKeyUp="return autoTab (this, 6, event);" onChange="disableButtons();">

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the javascript part of this so your issues lies elsewhere. That is assuming that at the time of execution your elements are there otherwise it obviously won't find them.

Comment: Your problem is that your JavaScript variable `query` has no value.  There is a separate AppleScript variable I can see you defined called `query`, which does have a value but then goes unused.  The other problem is your JavaScript isn’t targeted at a specific _Safari_ document or tab, so _Safari_ won’t know which tab to execute the script in.

Answer (score 0):

I outlined the problems with your script in the comment I left below your question.  To summarise:

① Your `query` variable is defined as an AppleScript variable, but goes unused.  You then make a reference to a variable in JavaScript called `query`, which is undefined and has no value.

② Your `do JavaScript` command has no target within *Safari*, which needs to perform the action on a specific tab or document.

#### Solution:

Without seeing the specific site you're working with, I cannot test my solution, but I'm pretty confident that it should rectify these two explicit errors that are most certainly preventing your script from working.  Whether or not any other unrelated issues crop up depends on the specifics of the website.

So you've defined your AppleScript variable `query`, which I'm just going to do lazily here:

```
    set query to "blah blah blah"
```

The core bit of your script needing amending is here:

```
    tell application "Safari" to tell ¬
        the front document to do JavaScript ¬
        "x=document.querySelectorAll(\"input[name$='_comment1']\"); " & ¬
        "for(let i of x){ i.value=" & quoted form of query & "; }"
```

Your JavaScript itself is totally fine (although I slightly modified it to my own preference, which I perhaps ought not to have done).  The main points here are that I have told *Safari* that it will be performing the JavaScript in the `front document`; and that the JavaScript now makes use of the AppleScript `query` variable with which it uses to set the value of the `<input>` fields.

Having tested a variant of this on some arbitrary website I found, it appeared successful.

Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I made the adjustment as you suggested. It didn't work but I found the problem. The webpage is made up of different frames and documents. I noticed the one I want is buried in the hierarchy. How can I access that document specifically?

Comment: @rpthomps Without seeing the source code for the webpage, it's difficult for me to offer assistance.  However, if you're looking at an `<iframe>` element that has a `#document` shadow element, these (for security reasons) aren't accessible in the same way that the rest of the HTML is.  I'm not aware of a way to get around this.